# How to Update a flutter app in play console

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play, updates

I have published an app in playstore and I want to update my app and also have made all the necessary changes in my code. Now, to release an update on play console, do I have to upload the whole aab file or is there a different file to upload(just the changes I made in my code).

Comment: You have to upload while aab file

Answer (score 6):

The Google Play Store prefers the app bundle format (aab). An Android App Bundle is a file (with the .aab file extension) that you upload to Google Play to support Dynamic Delivery.
So to make new changes that you made to your app's functionality - you should upload the aab file.You can find app bundle  files  located in `build/app/outputs` within your app’s folder.

The Dynamic Delivery feature then uses your app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs for each user’s device configuration, so they download only the code and resources they need to run your app.

1 Additional note : You may want to update the **version number** of your app too. 
The default version number of the app is 1.0.0. To update it, navigate to the `pubspec.yaml` file and update the following line:

version: 1.0.0+1

The version number is three numbers separated by dots, such as 1.0.0 in the example above, followed by an optional build number such as 1 in the example above, separated by a +.

Comment: I was confused that whether users had to download the whole file again, but your answer made it clear. Thanks

Comment: if my post helped you clear your point - you can accept it as "Answer" by clicking on the "accept/correct" sign

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should whole aab file

Don't forget to increase version info in **pubspec.yaml** file
(i.e: version: 1.0.2+2)